# extjs grid column header word wrap not working

Tags: css, extjs, grid

In my extjs6 grid I have column headers that don't fit in the space.  How do I do a word wrap in the column header only?  This is what I have tried and is not working.

```
                            xtype: 'grid',
                        title: 'Daily Performance',
                        itemId: 'performanceAccountDailyGridID',
                        bind: {
                            store: '{myDailyPerformanceAccountStore}'
                        },                            
                        margin: '10px 0px 10px 0px',
                        ui: 'featuredpanel-framed',
                        cls: 'custom-gridPerformance',
                        height: 400,
                        width: 800,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                header: 'Filedate',
                                dataIndex: 'filedate',
                                flex: 1
                            },
```

css

```
.custom-gridPerformance .x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text {
white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: `.custom-gridPerformance x-column-header {` would never match anything, is that a typo?

Comment: Not a typo. Just not sure proper format to use to edit the header. What should it be?

Comment: Because `x-column-header` isn't prefixed by `.`, then it's not matching the class name, it would be trying to match a tag where the tag name is `<x-column-header>`

Comment: So I just have to put a . Before x-column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You CSS selector should be nested till `.x-column-header-text` which contains the column header text.Just giving `white-space: normal` is sufficient.
So your CSS should be:

```
   .custom-gridPerformance .x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'region'],
    data: [{
        name: 'xyz',
        email: 'xyz@xyz.com',
        region: 'Arizona'
    }, {
        name: 'xyz',
        email: 'xyz@xyz.com',
        region: 'Alaska'
    }, {
        name: 'xyz',
        email: 'xyz@xyz.com',
        region: 'Alaska'
    }, {
        name: 'xyz',
        email: 'xyz@xyz.com',
        region: 'Alabama'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    width: 400,
      cls: 'custom-gridPerformance',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name of zoro of life style',
        dataIndex: 'name',

    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1,

    }, {
        text: 'State',
        dataIndex: 'region',
        
    }],
    

});
```

```css
.custom-gridPerformance .x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"><!-- framework javascript --><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: very weird, I see your code snippet works correctly when I run code snippet, but still does NOT work when I put in my code.  I changed my post and my code to reflect your css and still nothing.

Comment: What version and theme you are using?

Comment: extjs6 I believe, and     "toolkit": "classic",     
    /**
     * The name of the theme for this application.
     */
   "theme": "myCustomTheme",
   //"theme": "theme-triton",

Comment: .custom-gridPerformance .x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text {
    white-space: normal;
    font-size: 9px;
}

.custom-gridPerformance .x-column-header-inner {
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 3px !important;
    padding-bottom: 3px !important;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
}

Comment: I tried this solution with some success. The issue for me was that given a certain column width that caused wrapping, the wrap would sometimes push the header down and partially overlap the first row. Maybe test a few scenarios before committing to this solution.